# SSRS generated Excel reports and sharepoint searching

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So I have some Excel (.XLS) SSRS reports that get programmatically generated in an SSIS C# script task and uploaded to sharepoint.  We are **not** using XLSX (thats a different issue).

I am using SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services.  The Excel reports generated seem to be *"Microsoft Excel 2003-2007 Worksheet"*

The Excel reports are created in C# using the: `reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx`, and they are uploaded to sharepoint using the `_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx` SubmitFile method

This works fine, BUT the resulting EXCEL files are not searchable in sharepoint.  When searching for a String inside a file using the search option, the file is not returned.

It works when searching the CSV files which are uploaded.  Excel search is turned on and support in sharepoint.

BUT: If you download a report, open it in Excel (2010) and then SAVEAS (without any changes).  Then re-upload this saved file to Sharepoint, then the Sharepoint Search **DOES** work.

Note that when it is re-saved, it is still saved as *"Microsoft Excel 2003-2007 Worksheet"* .XLS, however the file size increases slightly.

Any ideas why the search is not working on the programmtically generated files, but works when you upload a re-saved version of the same file?

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2013/03/08/reportexecutionservice-render-method-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode.aspx) help?

Comment: thats more or less the exact code I am using to create the reports.  Doesn't explain why my reports are not searchable in sharepoint though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Sharepoint, about search not working when trying to search generated excel files from SSRS.

Checkout [this fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2678796). From the solution, it looks like a hot fix for SQL Server 2012 could resolve the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this, I'll try installing a hotfix but our SQL server 2010 editions have SP1 on them, and surely SP1 has this fix in it?

Comment: In the question, it is mentioned as the issue occurs in SQL server 2012 reporting services? The fix that has been provided for SQL 2008 SP2 and SQL 2012. I suppose applying the latest patches should work.